# Create managed property via powershell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server

I want to create a managed property via powershell in SharePoint 2013.
I found the parameters here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608089.aspx

Then I use `New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -Name "AboutMyCat" -SearchApplication "Search Service Application 1" -Type 1`

But an error appears `There was an internal problem connecting to or querying the database`

I am administrator of server. Is it the problem of permission ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error occurred due to couple of reason.

- when you are trying to create managed property with the same name which already exist.
- Or you dont have peroper permission on SharePoint Search service and DBs.

Further you should check the logs during the period and see if their is any access denied or other errors.

Comment: yes, I do not have permission of  SharePoint Search DBs.